# How to display SQL Server Unicode data with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

```
table 'abc' data :

    tid    title

      1      வெள்ளிக்கிழமை ஐ.

      2      கோலாகல தொடக்க 

    $sbd= mssql_pconnect('host', 'root',
    'root'); mssql_select_db('database',$sbd);
    $stmt=mssql_init("abcProcedure",
    $sbd); $result =
    mssql_execute($stmt); $row =
    mssql_fetch_assoc($result) echo

echo $row['title'];
```

Comment: And the charset for your HTML page is?????

Answer (score -1):

i think you could find something here

[Multibyte String Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php)